# Camel CXF Soap Client calling web service with multiple input parameters

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, cxf, cxf-client

I'm using Camel and have generated code from a WSDL using CXF. I generated a client stub and the implementation appears like this:

```
    SetDeviceDetailsv4 port = ss.getSetDeviceDetailsv4Port();  

    com.vodafone.gdsp.ws.SetDeviceDetailsv4_Type _setDeviceDetailsv4_parameters = null;
    com.vodafone.gdsp.ws.GdspHeader _setDeviceDetailsv4_gdspHeader = null;

    com.vodafone.gdsp.ws.SetDeviceDetailsv4Response _setDeviceDetailsv4__return = port.setDeviceDetailsv4(_setDeviceDetailsv4_parameters, _setDeviceDetailsv4_gdspHeader);

    System.out.println("setDeviceDetailsv4.result=" + _setDeviceDetailsv4__return);
```

As you one can see, the port takes two parameters and returns the response, which I want to delegate back to my Camel Route. What's the best way to implement this in Camel? I already have my CXF Enpoint defined, I'm just struggling with the DSL Routing part of it. Should I add a processor like what is found in this link? [Apache Camel and web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276308/apache-camel-and-web-services)

Thanks

Comment: Did you write camel route. If yes share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it but I added both of my "input" objects as a Camel Header, then I wrote a processor that grabbed what I needed and put the two objects that the service call needed as parameters.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
        gdspHeader = inMessage.getHeader(GDSP_HEADER, com.vodafone.gdsp.ws.GdspHeader.class);
        commModule = inMessage.getHeader(COMM_MODULE_HEADER, resmed.hi.ngcs.datastore.model.CommModule.class);
        SetDeviceDetailsv4_Type deviceDetails = createSetDeviceDetailsv4(commModule);

        List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(deviceDetails);
        params.add(gdspHeader);

        inMessage.setBody(params);

    }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jax-ws client (implement as bean) and use it in camel DSL. JAX-WS client bean definition takes service class/interface and allow you configure additional properties like SSL config & etc. In route, we can use it as bean. It takes JAXB generated Request object (WSDL request object) as input and returns the JAXB generated Response Object (WSDL response object). To convert you pojo to JAXB classes, Dozer framework can be used or custom mapping can be also used. 
Jax-WS client is also flexible to take XML as request and response. In that case, properties need to be set as DATAFORMAT as PAYLOAD.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because we're in Karaf (OSGI) and using Blueprint instead of Spring context but I get XML parsing errors when I load my app stating that dataFormat is not valid option. We're using CXF 2.7.7 and camel 2.12.4, so that could be an issue too

Comment: Can you post your config file? Ideally DATAFORMAT should be set in jax-ws properties