# Camel With Cxf and Routing

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, cxf

I was doing some research on Camel - CXf integration and am confused about the below scenario.

So i implemented a Rest Endpoint

```
@Path("/authenticate")
public interface Sample {
@GET
@Path("/handshake")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response handshake();

@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(LoginRequest request) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException;
}
```

And the implementation as below

```
public class SampleImpl implements Sample{

@Context
private HttpHeaders headers;

@Autowired
CamelContext context;

public Response handshake()
{
    System.out.println("HandShake Executed Successfully");
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("This is a Message after Routing").build();
}

public Response login(LoginRequest request) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    System.out.println("The Rquest objecr is Received "+request);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(mapper.writeValueAsString(request)).build();
}
```

}

The Route

```
<camel:from uri="cxfrs:bean:SampleRestEndPoint?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer"></camel:from>
```

routes it into the implementation. But since the implementation returns a response object am confused how to build the routes around this.

1. Once the call comes into the implementation how can I execute the
   other routes and sent a response back?.In this case the implementation returns a custom object.
2. How are the other routes attached to a CXF route?.
3. Should my CXF Implemenation always return a void type?. As i see
   that, to get access to Exchange object camel need the return type to
   be void
4. Do I completely ignore the implementation and go with the "to" steps
       and modify it in exchange body for the required response?.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GauthamHonnavara - that is an implementation of a JS webservice with an assosiated processor however it doesnt assosiate any direct route to the endpoint.Also my question was specific to JAX-RS where you cannot generate a service class from wsdl.

Assume this use case that u need a customer to invoke the endpoint and then go through say another 5 steps, reach out to another webservice etc and then sent a response back. The above implementation sents a response back in the webservice implementation bean itself.

So to avoid this create a simple interface with the producer consumer etc, just like in my question and then make each method void if you want to  inject the Exchange( if needed. ) and use below configuration

```
<!-- Created the CXF End Point For the  Calls to Come IN -->
<cxf:rsServer id="RestEndPoint" address="/rest"
    serviceClass="com.poc.camel.cxf.service.incoming.xxx"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20">
    <cxf:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" >
            <!-- <constructor-arg ref="customObjectMapper" type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/> -->
        </bean>
    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsServer>
```

Trick is to use the service class tag. If the interface is provided there then it doesn't need a concrete implementation from CXF.

Hope this helps. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Dude, take a look at this - http://bushorn.com/camel-cxf-geocoder-example/

The above example is not REST though, but usage of CXF with Camel route is same.

I will do these mandatory steps:

1. Avoid beans/custom classes - try to use the camel framework capabilities.
2. Use XML - Spring/Blueprint DSL

Comment: Thanks for the reply however this is not what i am looking for. I want to have an example where the CSF webservice is implemented and acts as an endpoint, on trigger the endpoint should go through a route and return a response. Looks like a straight for test case but cant find an example or solve the problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following thread.

[Apache Camel and web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276308/apache-camel-and-web-services/33108186#33108186)

I have successfully implemented web service consumption using camel and Apache CXF. If you have doubts, I can help you out.

Thanks,
Gautham